# Form's being sent from root instead user mail

Tags: email, web-server, web

I have server which is hosting few websites. When user fills form on a website I get it from root@webserver instead from mail which belongs to the hosted website. How can I check why is this happening?
Webserver is running RedHat 5 linux.

Comment: Give us a clue - what is sending the mail - Java? PHP? Perl? Is it invoked over CGI? FastCGI? What is the MTA? How is it configured?

Comment: @symcbean  I'm using php script and MTA being used is Qmail

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the mail server (which is the software actually doing the delivery) to re-write the mail headers for you. The default mail program for Red Hat 5 is Sendmail but you can easily use Postfix instead (I find postfix easier to configure especially if you are new to mail servers).

To change the name after the @ you need to use the masquerading configuration options. See the documentation for how to do this (or do some Google-ing) but I recommend reading up on how mail servers work a little first.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-email-mta.html

Comment: I have just checked other sites and it seems that they are working fine, only one is  still showing root@servername instead of  e-mail which user provided when filling web form.